# How do I count cell values in one column using a criteria of another column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have X,Y data in two columns (A,B) of an Excel spreadsheet. I want to count the values in the B column using a criteria of the A-column. Specifically, the A,B column data are dates and occurrences of an event on that given day. But I want the counts based on each week, not each day (column E in the image). COUNTIF won't work but was wondering how this can be accomplished. As you can see in the spreadsheet, there are two occurrence for the week of 9/30/2018 to 10/6/2018 (1 event each on 10/3 and 9/30), so in cell F2 we have 2.

[image: Need Formula to count by week]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `SUMIFS`, e.g. type this into cell `F2` and drag down:

```
= SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<="&E2,A:A,">="&(E2-6))
```

See below working example.

[image]

Comment: perfect - works beautifully, thanks!